# Regexp: Replace when word found

Tags: javascript, regex, string, regexp-replace

I want to replace a word when expression `" : "` with `{{}}`.

This is my first try with regexp and i don't know how to do it.

This is what i have :

```
/:id/user 
/auth/:token
```

This is how i want it to be :

```
/{{id}}/user
/auth/{{token}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.replace()` with a regex as first parameter. In the second one, `$1` will be replaced by what is found between the first parenthesis pair in your regex.

```js
const str = "/:id/user/:param/:8d"
const result = str.replace(/:(\w+)/g, '{{$1}}')

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can match `/:id` and with `replace` take off the `/:` and add `{{}}`

```js
const url = "/:id/user"
const url2 = "/auth/:token"

const res = url2.replace(/\/:\w*/g, match =>  `/{{${match.substring(2,match.length)}}}`)

console.log(res)
```